What is the Understanding level required in mathematics to become a great data scientist?
I am a civil engineer and i got some undergraduate courses in linear algebra, probability and statistics.
I am pursuing some ML/DS courses in udemy so I'm just a beginner and I would like to become a good data scientist in one year ( like being in top 10 % in kaggle competitions and achieve some interesting real life DS projects ). May be one day who knows ? I will build my own competitive ML model.
But i was asking myself what is the mathematics understanding level required to succeed in this path. For example, you can master some probability formulas, statistics hypothesis tests without knowing rigorous measure theory and probability theory foundations. You can deal with matrices operations without mastering mathematical logic, axiomatic set theory and proofs techniques. You can write some code without knowing deeply mathematical computation theory.
So please what is the maths understanding level required ? We can may be categorize different levels for beginners, intermediates, advanced data scientists and the greatest data scientists ( praticians and researchers ) ?
Thank you.
